# Should I merge working branch to master branch of super project that has submodules?

Tags: git

I have a super project that has few submodules. e.g.: sub1, sub2 and sub3.

To start work, I create a branch "working" on super project.  This working branch also modify code in sub1 and sub3.  I create branch "working" for sub1 and sub3 too.

I commit some changes in sub1 and sub3 on "working" branch and also stage and commit changes on super project too under "working" branch.

I may then switch between "master" and "working" branch on super project and I may see my new changes are shown in "working" branch only.

Now, I want to merge the "working" branch to "master" branch.  I go to sub1, merge "working" to "master".  I go to sub3, merge "working" to "master".

Now, in "master" branch of super project, both sub1 and sub3 is modified.  Shall I add and commit sub1 and sub3 in "master" branch and ignore "working" branch?  Or I should merge "master" of super project with "working" of super project?

I am confuse here.  Is the workflow I use from beginning correct with submodules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, after you run merge on your main project, is to use:

```
git submodule update --merge
```

You can see more details @ the [git submodule man-page](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html)

Comment: I am using smartgit, do you have any ideas how run "git submodule update --merge" in smartgit?

Comment: I think there is no way to do it.